# How to refresh API data every x seconds

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api

I'm trying to create my own crypto portfolio for that I am using Wazirx API for fetching details. I've Successfully fetched and displayed some neeeded datas from that API. But I don't know how to refresh that price every x seconds.

have tried setinterval method to refresh but it's not working may be i may used that method wrong.

**Note:**
**This is my updated code i've modified its working and prices are refreshig per second perfectly but why its showing only the first data from the API is there any mistake in my for loop.**

```html
<div id="demo2"></div>

<script>

var data, len, len1, name, symbol, currency, price;

const api_url = "https://api.wazirx.com/api/v2/market-status";

async function get_data_from_api() {
    
const response = await fetch(api_url);

data = await response.json();

    len = Object.keys(data["markets"]).length;
    len1 = Object.keys(data["assets"]).length;

    for(let i=0; i< len; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<len1; j++){
            if(data['markets'][i]['baseMarket'] == data['assets'][j]['type'] && data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'] == "inr") { 

                name   = data['assets'][j]['name'];
                symbol = data['assets'][j]['type'];
                currency    = data['markets'][i]['quoteMarket'];
                price   = data['markets'][i]['buy'];

                document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = name +" "+ symbol +" "+ currency +" "+ price;
            
            }
        }
    }

}

setInterval(get_data_from_api, 1000);

get_data_from_api();

</script>
```

Comment: _"have tried setinterval method to refresh but it's not working"_... please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68765412/edit) to show your attempt

Comment: See the code now

Comment: That should make your page reload every second. Does that not work? Are there any errors reported in your browser console?

Comment: Yes its making my page reload every 1 second but i dont want that how can i refresh that price details alone? And there's no error showing in my browser console!

Comment: Make an AJAX request to your page, extract the details you want and replace them in the current page

Comment: I've modifed my code its refreshing every per second perfectly but it just showing first record from that API. I don't know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: We don't either, so make the code tell you what's available. Try adding a `console.log(data["markets"]);` and a `console.log(data["assets"]);` after where you set the lengths to see what the response contains. Then check the browser console for those items to see the structure.

Comment: Found Answer problem is in innerhtml i have to put += after inner html